# Dual boot USB memory stick with file partition

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, usb

Here is what Im looking after to being able to use an usb stick that upon booting will show a similar bootloader when you normally boot your computer. With the selection of which OS you want to install, Ubuntu or Windows 10 in this case. But as this will leave lots of extra space on the memory stick. I want the rest of the thumbdrive being accessable by both windows and ubuntu. And as far as I've understood the only way for this is if the first data partition on the usb stick is in NTFS format.

I've had serious mishaps, somehow I even deleted my UEFI bios and bricked my computer (was overly tired and did not realize what drive I was messing with). Tried alof ot different programs, and read a bunch of suggestions here.

This was the one that made the most sense to me.

[How to create a multi-partition USB drive that also acts as the bootable ubuntu.iso?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1284791/how-to-create-a-multi-partition-usb-drive-that-also-acts-as-the-bootable-ubuntu/1284930#1284930) but there are a few things in there that I dont quite get, and feel wont work as I need that NTFS partition.

[This was my idea of how to set up the partitions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zIx7N.png)

But it feels like something is not right. I havent even begun on the bootloader yet and how to set that up.

Anything to steer me in the right way would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Ventoy creates a USB that will boot multiple Linux OS and Windows installer. There is a Widows version and a Ubuntu version. It installs onto an exFAT partition so it can also be used for Windows and Linux data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Ventoy

**I think Ventoy will do what you want**

1. Ventoy will boot the Windows installer ISO and almost any Linux ISO: https://www.ventoy.net/en/index.html
2. Ventoy will boot a Linux ISO either Live or Persistent modes. It will boot multiple ISO's, just drag and drop the ISO's onto the USB.
3. Ventoy will make persistence files greater than 4GB and having exFAT file system has "unlimited storage". Information on the persistence plugin is on this page: https://www.ventoy.net/en/plugin_persistence.html
4. Ventoy uses the familiar GRUB2 bootloader.
5. There is a Windows version and a Ubuntu version of Ventoy.

Comment: It looks like my idea to have the different installs on separate partitions was unessecary. This worked out perfectly. Thanks!