# Need to move photos from hard drive onto USB but Ubuntu does not have enough space to boot

Tags: boot, usb

Basically,
I put a bunch of images on my laptop and then downloaded some programs and turned it off after the computer told me there wasn't enough space on the disk. Already cleaned it up, but it still won't boot - it still fails to start GNOME. I only have one flashdrive right now, so I can't move the photos from that one even if I decided to boot from USB. Any way to move files from my computer to the usb through the boot menu?

Comment: I don’t think this is the easiest way to do what you want; you can create a usb installation drive with another partition for data - that has to be easier? Have a look here https://askubuntu.com/questions/1284791/how-to-create-a-multi-partition-usb-drive-that-also-acts-as-the-bootable-ubuntu

Comment: You can create a persistent live system on the USB pendrive with [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb) - Such a system will boot like a normal live system (from the USB pendrive), but it has a writable partition, where files can be stored (and even program packages can be installed). Whatever you save in your 'Downloads', 'Pictures' etc directories will be stored automatically in the writable partition. - But beware, a USB pendrive is not as reliable as an HDD or SSD, and you can easily make the file system corrupted, so please get a better storage medium for important files.

Comment: You may need [to borrow] another computer in order to create the persistent live system. If no Linux is available, you can use [Rufus](https://rufus.ie) in Windows to create the persistent live system. - If your USB pendrive is too small for both the operating system and the photos, you may need [to borrow] another USB pendrive.

Answer (score 0):

Do you get GRUB menu?
if you have GRUB menu you can edit the boot option to come into /bin/bash root session and from there copy the files to USB perhaps.
You can come into the root session if you come to the option in GRUB that you want to use, type 'e' and add instead of `ro quiet splash ...` write `rw init=/bin/bash` in the linux line and press F10

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).